# First Person Camera issue in OpenTK

Tags: c#, camera, opentk

I have been coding on OpenTK and so far, I wrote a script where a grass textured cube rotates with lighting on. I have made it that the cube can move using W A D S except to simulate an first person perspective, I made the cube move in opposite directions. I wanted to create a lookAt function and it's not working. I have searched for tutorials but non of them work. Now I'm stuck, could someone please help me?

```
void Start()
    {
        window.Load += loaded;
        window.Resize += resize;
        window.RenderFrame += renderF;
        window.KeyPress += keyPress;
        window.Run(1.0/60.0);
    }

    void resize(object ob,EventArgs e)
    {
        GL.Viewport(0,0,window.Width,window.Height);
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.LoadIdentity();
        Matrix4 matrix = Matrix4.Perspective(45.0f,window.Width/window.Height,1.0f,1000.0f);

        Matrix4 view = Matrix4.LookAt(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 
        0.0f),newVector3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f),newVector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        Vector3 Position = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
        GL.LoadMatrix(ref matrix);
        //GL.LoadMatrix(ref view);
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
    }


    void renderF(object o , EventArgs e)
    {
        GL.LoadIdentity();
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        //CUBE 1:
        GL.PushMatrix();

        GL.Translate(x,y,z);
        GL.Rotate(theta,1.0,0.0,0.0);
        GL.Rotate(theta,1.0,0.0,1.0);
        GL.Scale(0.7,0.7,0.7);

        draw_cube();

        GL.PopMatrix();

        window.SwapBuffers();

        theta += count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) there are different current matrices. See [`MatrixMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/opentk.graphics.es11.matrixmode?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12).
The projection matrix has to be set to the the current  `MatrixMode.Projection` matrix and the model matrix to the current `MatrixMode.Modelview`. The current matrix mode has to be set before the operation which manipulates the matrix.

The 1st argument of [`Matrix4.LookAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/opentk.matrix4.lookat?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) defines the position of the viewer and the 2nd argument the target. Th vector from the viewing position to the target defines the line of sight. The 3rd argument is the up-vector:

```cs
void resize(object ob,EventArgs e)
{
    GL.Viewport(0,0,window.Width,window.Height);

    Matrix4 matrix = Matrix4.Perspective(45.0f,window.Width/window.Height,1.0f,1000.0f);
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
    GL.LoadMatrix(ref matrix);
}

void renderF(object o , EventArgs e)
{
    Matrix4 view = Matrix4.LookAt(
        new Vector3(0.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f),
        new Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f),
        new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
    GL.LoadMatrix(ref view);

    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
    // [...]
}
```

---

Anyway I recommend not to use deprecated [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL). Read a good OpenGL tutorial like [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/) and use [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader). Some OpenTK examples can be found at [GitHub - Rabbid76/c_sharp_opengl](https://github.com/Rabbid76/c_sharp_opengl)

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: @Person Sorry, my bad. `-0.3f` had to be `-3.0f` (`Matrix4.LookAt`).

Comment: @Person Thank you. You're welcome. Stay active and you can vote soon.